# How to replace different blocks of text in all combinations using awk?

Tags: python, regex, bash, perl, awk

I'm trying to replace blocks of lines like this pattern:

- A block of lines is formed by the lines bellow which has an minor number.
- When a line has the "=", then this block of lines could replace the block named after the "="

Let's see an example, this input:

```
01 hello
    02 stack
    02 overflow
        04 hi
    02 friends = overflow
        03 this
        03 is 
        03 my = is
        03 life
    02 lol
    02 im
    02 joking = im
        03 filler
```

Would generate the following ouput (each hello block is one element of an array):

```
01 hello
    02 stack
    02 overflow
        04 hi
    02 lol
    02 im

01 hello
    02 stack
    02 overflow
        04 hi
    02 lol
    02 joking = im
        03 filler

01 hello
    02 stack
    02 friends = overflow
        03 this
        03 is 
        03 life
    02 lol
    02 im

01 hello
    02 stack
    02 friends = overflow
        03 this
        03 is 
        03 life
    02 lol
    02 joking = im
        03 filler

01 hello
    02 stack
    02 friends = overflow
        03 this
        03 my = is
        03 life
    02 lol
    02 im

01 hello
    02 stack
    02 friends = overflow
        03 this
        03 my = is
        03 life
    02 lol
    02 joking = im
        03 filler
```

I tried it by this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '{

    if ($0~/=/){
      level=$1
      oc=1
    }else if (oc && $1<=level){
        oc=0
    }

    if (!oc){
        print
    }

}' input.txt
```

But it only returns the first output that I need, and I don't know how to skip the `03 life` word which are within `friends`.

How could I generate these outputs?

I wouldn't mind a python or perl solution if is more confortable to you.

Comment: Yeah, maybe you are right. I'll rethink how to simplify it. The point is that I want to put an example which includes all the caseloads, so the output is too large...

Comment: Your problem description does not match the output you generate. What other rules are you implicitly following to generate the output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a python script to read the cobol input file and print out all the possible combinations of defined and redefined variables:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
"""Read cobol file and print all possible redefines."""
import sys
from itertools import product

def readfile(fname):
    """Read cobol file & return a master list of lines and namecount of redefined lines."""
    master = []
    namecount = {}
    with open(fname) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip(' .\t\n')
            if not line:
                continue
            words = line.split()
            n = int(words[0])
            if '=' in words or 'REDEFINES' in words:
                name = words[3]
            else:
                name = words[1]
            master.append((n, name, line))
            namecount[name] = namecount.get(name, 0) + 1
    # py2.7: namecount = {key: val for key, val in namecount.items() if val > 1}
    namecount = dict((key, val) for key, val in namecount.items() if val > 1)

    return master, namecount

def compute(master, skip=None):
    """Return new cobol file given master and skip parameters."""
    if skip is None:
        skip = {}
    seen = {}
    skip_to = None
    output = ''
    for n, name, line in master:
        if skip_to and n > skip_to:
            continue
        seen[name] = seen.get(name, 0) + 1
        if seen[name] != skip.get(name, 1):
            skip_to = n
            continue
        skip_to = None
        output += line + '\n' 
    return output

def find_all(master, namecount):
    """Return list of all possible output files given master and namecount."""
    keys = namecount.keys()
    values = [namecount[k] for k in keys]
    out = []
    for combo in product(*[range(1, v + 1) for v in values]):
        skip = dict(zip(keys, combo))
        new = compute(master, skip=skip)
        if new not in out:
            out.append(new)
    return out

def main(argv):
    """Process command line arguments and print results."""
    fname = argv[-1]
    master, namecount = readfile(fname)
    out = find_all(master, namecount)
    print('\n'.join(out))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

If the above script is save in a file called `cobol.py`, then if can be run as:

```
python cobol.py name_of_input_file
```

The various possible combinations of defines and redefines will be displayed on stdout.

This script runs under either python2 (2.6+) or python3.

#### Explanation

The code uses three functions:

- `readfile` reads the input file and returns two variables that summarize the structure of what is in it.
- `compute` takes two parameters and, from them, computes an output block.
- `find_all` determines all the possible output blocks, uses `compute` to create them, and then returns them as a list.

Let's look at each function in more detail:

1. `readfile`

`readfile` takes the input file name as an argument and returns a list, `master`, and a dictionary, `namecount`.  For every non-empty line in the input file, the list `master` has a tuple containing (1) the level number, (2) the name that is defined or redefined, and (2) the original line itself.  For the sample input file, `readfile` returns this value for `master`:

```
[(1, 'hello', '01 hello'),
 (2, 'stack', '    02 stack'),
 (2, 'overflow', '    02 overflow'),
 (4, 'hi', '        04 hi'),
 (2, 'overflow', '    02 friends = overflow'),
 (3, 'this', '        03 this'),
 (3, 'is', '        03 is'),
 (3, 'is', '        03 my = is'),
 (3, 'life', '        03 life'),
 (2, 'lol', '    02 lol'),
 (2, 'im', '    02 im'),
 (2, 'im', '    02 joking = im'),
 (3, 'filler', '        03 filler')]
```

`readfile` also returns the dictionary `namecount` which has an entry for every name that gets redefined and has a count of how many definitions/redefinitions there are for that name.  For the sample input file, `namecount` has the value:

```
{'im': 2, 'is': 2, 'overflow': 2}
```

This indicates that `im`, `is`, and `overflow` each have two possible values.

`readfile` was of course designed to work with the input file format in the current version of the question.  To the extent possible, it was also designed to work with the formats from the previous versions of this question.  For example, variable redefinitions are accepted whether they are signaled with an equal sign (current version) or with the word `REFDEFINES` as in previous versions.  This is intended to make this script as flexible as possible.

2. `compute`

The function `compute` is what generates each output block.  It uses two parameters.  The first is `master` which comes directly from `readfile`.  The second is `skip` which is derived from the `namecount` dictionary that was returned by `readfile`.  For example, the `namecount` dictionary says that there are two possible definitions for `im`.  This shows how `compute` can be used to generate the output block for each:

```
In [14]: print compute(master, skip={'im':1, 'is':1, 'overflow':1})
01 hello
    02 stack
    02 overflow
        04 hi
    02 lol
    02 im

In [15]: print compute(master, skip={'im':2, 'is':1, 'overflow':1})
01 hello
    02 stack
    02 overflow
        04 hi
    02 lol
    02 joking = im
        03 filler
```

Observe that the first call to `compute` above generated the block that uses the first definition of `im` and the second call generated the block that uses the second definition.

3. `find_all`

With the above two functions available, it is clear that the last step is just to generate all the different combinations of definitions and print them out.  That is what the function `find_all` does.  Using `master` and `namecount` as returned by `readfile`, it systematic runs through all the available combinations of definitions and calls `compute` to create a block for each one.  It gathers up all the unique blocks that can be created this way and returns them.

The output returned by `find_all` is a list of strings.  Each strings is the block which corresponds to one combination of defines/redefines.  Using the sample input from the question, this shows what `find_all` returns:

```
In [16]: find_all(master, namecount)
Out[16]: 
['01 hello\n    02 stack\n    02 overflow\n        04 hi\n    02 lol\n    02 im\n',
 '01 hello\n    02 stack\n    02 friends = overflow\n        03 this\n        03 is\n        03 life\n    02 lol\n    02 im\n',
 '01 hello\n    02 stack\n    02 overflow\n        04 hi\n    02 lol\n    02 joking = im\n        03 filler\n',
 '01 hello\n    02 stack\n    02 friends = overflow\n        03 this\n        03 is\n        03 life\n    02 lol\n    02 joking = im\n        03 filler\n',
 '01 hello\n    02 stack\n    02 friends = overflow\n        03 this\n        03 my = is\n        03 life\n    02 lol\n    02 im\n',
 '01 hello\n    02 stack\n    02 friends = overflow\n        03 this\n        03 my = is\n        03 life\n    02 lol\n    02 joking = im\n        03 filler\n']
```

As an example, let's take the fourth string returned by `find_all` and, for better format, we will `print` it:

```
In [18]: print find_all(master, namecount)[3]
01 hello
    02 stack
    02 friends = overflow
        03 this
        03 is
        03 life
    02 lol
    02 joking = im
        03 filler
```

In the complete script, the output from `find_all` is combined together and printed to stdout as follows:

```
out = find_all(master, namecount)              
print('\n'.join(out))
```

In this way, the output displays all possible blocks.

### Answers for Earlier Versions of the Question

#### Answer for Original Question

```
awk 'f==0 && !/REDEFINES/{s=s"\n"$0;next} /REDEFINES/{f=1;print s t>("output" ++c ".txt");t=""} {t=t"\n"$0} END{print s t>("output" ++c ".txt")}' input
```

#### Explanation:

This program has the following variables:

- `f` is a flag which is zero before the first REDEFINE and one thereafter.
- `s` contains all the text up to the first REDEFINE.
- `t` contains the text of the current REDEFINE.
- `c` is a counter which is used to determine the name of the output name.

The code works as follows:

1. `f==0 && !/REDEFINES/{s=s"\n"$0;next}`

   Before the first redefine is encountered, the text is saved in the variable `s` and we skip the rest of the commands and jump to the `next` line.
2. `/REDEFINES/{f=1;print s t>("output" ++c ".txt");t=""}`

   Every time that we encounter a REDEFINE line, we set the flag `f` to one and print the prolog section `s` along with the current REDEFINE section to a file named `outputn.txt` where n is replaced by the value of the counter `c`.

   Because we are at the start of a new REDEFINE section, the variable `t` is set to empty.
3. `{t=t"\n"$0}`

   Save the current line of this REDEFINE to the variable `t`.
4. `END{print s t>("output" ++c ".txt")}`

   The output file for the last REDEFINE section is printed.

#### A Minor Improvement

Each of the output files produced by the code above has a leading blank line.  The code below removes that via the `awk` `substr` function:

```
awk '/REDEFINES/{f=1;print substr(s,2) t>("output" ++c ".txt");t=""} f==0 {s=s"\n"$0;next} {t=t"\n"$0} END{print substr(s,2) t>("output" ++c ".txt")}' input
```

For variety, this version has slightly different logic but, otherwise, achieves the same result.

#### Answer for Revised Question

```
awk 'f==1 && pre==$1 && !/REDEFINES/{tail=tail "\n" $0} /REDEFINES/{pre=$1;f=1;t[++c]="\n"$0} f==0 {head=head"\n"$0;next} pre!=$1{t[c]=t[c]"\n"$0} END{for (i=0;i<=c;i++) {print head t[i] tail>("output" (i+1) ".txt")}}' file
```

Comment: Works like a charm! There is another case that I hadn't contemplated. Check the input and output examples of my answer again, please. Thank you! :)

Comment: @JohnDoe See revised answer.

Comment: Hello John, is awesome, but there is still a case which had not contemplated. I have updated the question again. With this, it would be finished, I promise. :P Thank you in advance. And for the detailed explanation too.

Comment: It's too complex to parse it with awk? would be better with another pure bash?

Comment: @JohnDoe That does make for quite a major change in the algorithm.  To try to clarify what you are looking for, I numbered the new desired outputs.  Some clarification would help.  For example, output 2 never defines `HOLA` but it has `DERE REDEFINES HOLA`.  Is that intentional?

Comment: I've edited the question again. I've explanied it the best I could. Now is crystal clear. :P And answering your question: yes, as you can see, each redefine replacement of the output deletes the variable which are redifying and the others redefines of this variable. We got the same case in `DELE3 REDEFINES DERE2.` of output3.txt. Let me know any doubt, and thank you for our time. :)

Comment: @Jhon1024, could you comment the code? its pretty awesome! :) Thank you!

Comment: BTW, I'm afraid it does not runs over python2: `SyntaxError: ('invalid syntax', ('cobol.py', 24, 29, '    namecount = {key: val for key, val in namecount.items() if val > 1}\n'))`

Comment: @Joana That means that you are running python2.6  I had tested under py2.7 but I just modified the code to be python2.6 compatible.  So, try the new version.  Also, I just made a start on explaining the code.  I will continue to add more explanation as the day goes on.

Comment: @Joana I have just added a longer explanation.  Let me know if you have questions.